# Finding the cardinality of the centralizer in the permutation groups.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, solution-verification

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be a permutation. Find a formula (in terms of the factorization of $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles) for the cardinality of $C_{S_n}(\sigma)$. Fix $n$; for which permutations $\sigma$ the minimum is obtained?

Hi. I would like to know if my reasoning is correct. I attach my solution.

Let $\sigma\in S_n$.  We put this permutation in its decomposition of disjoint cycles $\sigma=(a_1^{1}\ldots a_{m_1}^{1})\cdots (a_{1}^{k}\ldots a_{m_k}^{k}) $

Let $\tau\in C_{S_n}(\sigma)$. Then $\tau\sigma=\sigma\tau$ equivalent $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma$

Now, \begin{eqnarray}
\tau(a_1^{1}\ldots a_{m_1}^{1})\tau^{-1}\cdots \tau(a_{1}^{k}\ldots a_{m_k}^{k})\tau^{-1}&&=(\tau(a_1^{1})\ldots \tau(a_{m_1}^{1}))\cdots (\tau(a_{1}^{k})\ldots \tau(a_{m_k}^{k}))\\
&&=(a_1^{1}\ldots a_{m_1}^{1})\cdots (a_{1}^{k}\ldots a_{m_k}^{k})
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\tau(a_1^{1}) \text{ can be } m_1+\cdots +m_k \text{ posibility and } \tau(a_2^{1}),\cdots \tau(a_{m_1}^{1}) \text{ are determined }\\
&&\tau(a_1^{2}) \text{ can be } m_2+\cdots +m_k \text{ posibility and } \tau(a_2^{2}),\cdots \tau(a_{m_2}^{2}) \text{ are determined}\\
&&\vdots\\
&&\tau(a_1^{k}) \text{ can be } m_k \text{ posibility and } \tau(a_2^{k}),\cdots \tau(a_{m_k}^{k}) \text{ are determined}\\
\end{eqnarray}

Further, exists $(n-(m_1+\cdots+m_k))!$ ways to permute $\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}\setminus\{a_1^{1},\ldots, a_{m_1}^{1},\ldots a_{1}^{k}\ldots,a_{m_k}^{k}\}$

Therefore, $|C_{S_n}(\sigma)|=[(m_1+\cdots+m_k)(m_2+\cdots +m_k)\cdots m_k ](n-(m_1+\cdots+m_k))!$

This is correct?

**Actualization.**

Now,I think that fix this.

Let $\sigma\in S_n$. Then $\sigma=\sigma_{1}^{1}\cdots \sigma_{n_1}^{1}\cdots \sigma_{1}^{k}\cdots \sigma_{n_k}^{k}$ where $\sigma_{1}^{j},\ldots, \sigma_{n_{j}}^{j}$ are $n_j$ cycles of large $m_j,\quad j=1,\ldots, k$

Therefore, $|C_{S_n}(\sigma)|=\prod_{i=1}^{k}n_im_i(n-\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_im_i)!$

For $\sigma=(12)(345)\in S_5, |C_{S_5}(\sigma)|=(1\cdot 2)(1\cdot 3)(5-(1\cdot 2+1\cdot 3))!=6$

Comment: Are you assuming $m_1,...,m_k > 1$? Also, are you assuming a particular ordering of $m_1,...,m_k$ (e.g., $m_1\le \cdots\le m_k$)? Note that your formula is not independent of the choice of ordering.

Comment: In any case, for $n=5$, if $\sigma=(1\;2)(3\;4\;5)$, the centralizer of $\sigma$ has cardinality $6$, which doesn't seem to match your proposed formula.

Comment: Fix $\sigma\in S_n$, and for $k\in\{1,...,n\}$, let $x_k$ be the number of $k$-cycles in the disjoint cycle representation of $\sigma$. Then based on sample data, it's evident that  
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\Bigl(\bigl(k^{x_k}\bigr)(x_k!)\Bigr)
$$
correctly measures the cardinality of the centralizer of $\sigma$.

Comment: thanks. I already saw my mistake, I think I can fix it. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Now, I think fix this in the thread.

Comment: Your current version doesn't seem to work for $\sigma=(1\;2)(3\;4)$ in $S_4$.